# How to calculate average queue length in SQL Server from an event log table

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I'm monitoring a system that receives events onto a queue and processes them in order/sequentially/one at a time. The events are generated by a physical devices that run continuously (24x7, 365 days a year). Individual devices may come off line for maintenance, but the process doesn't stop.

The system provider is updating it and I'm trying to profile the performance over time with 2 metrics:

1. Daily average of the length of time an event stays in the queue
2. Daily average queue length (data points being how long was the queue when a new event was added)

An event arrives in the queue in an "Active" state, the processor sets the event to "Complete" if it has been successfully processed and "Invalid" if it fails after 5 retry attempts. Only after an event is marked as "Complete" or "Invalid" does the processor move on to the next event. The result of the process is updates to the fact tables other systems use.

We've got a log of the following to a table in SQL Server:

1. The Id of the event, generated as a sequential integer. Logically (but not actually) this works like `IDENTITY(1,1)`
2. The current state of the event, a foreign key, can only be: Active, Completed or Invalid
3. The date and time the event generated
4. The date and time the state was set to "Completed" or "Invalid"
5. The number of retry attempts (details or the reason for the failure are stored elsewhere)

The log table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EventLog (
    Id int NOT NULL,
    StateId int NOT NULL,
    Generated datetime NULL,
    Modified datetime NOT NULL,
    Retries int NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( Id ASC ))
```

I've also got an index on the 2 dates and the stateId

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EventLog_DatesState ON EventLog
(
    Generated ASC,
    Modified ASC,
    StateId ASC
)
```

I can use `DATEDIFF(SECOND, Generated, Modified )/60.0` to calculate the time an event spends in the queue in minutes. I can then average that per day to see how it changes over time.

Calculating the average queue length for a day can be difficult. To get the queue length at the enqueue time for an item I tried:

```
WITH EventDuration (SELECT
    CAST(Generated AS Date) GeneratedDate
    , DATEDIFF(SECOND, Generated, Modified)/60.0 TimeMinutes
    , (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM EventLog sub
        WHERE EventLog.Generated between sub.Generated and sub.Modified
        AND StateId != @ActiveState
    ) queueLength
FROM EventLog
WHERE StateId != @ActiveState)
SELECT 
    GeneratedDate
    , AVG(TimeMinutes) AvgTime
    , AVG(QueueLength) AvgLength
    , COUNT(*) Count
FROM EventDuration
GROUP BY GeneratedDate 
ORDER BY GeneratedDate DESC
```

But that self join/subquery takes to query from sub-second to I gave up after >10 minutes.

I've got about 175000 rows in the table. Any recommended approaches?

---

The execution plan shows the expensive parts of the query are:

1. Index Spool (51%)

   - Output List: `EventLog.StateId`, `EventLog.Modified`
   - Seek Predicate: `Seek Keys[1]: End: EventLog.Generated < Scalar Operator(EventLog.Generated)`
2. Filter (40%)

   - Predicate: `EventLog.Modified as sub.Modified>EventLog.Generated AND EventLog.StateId as sub.StateId<>(0)`

[image: screen shot of the expensive part of the query plan]

---

Other context/notes:

1. The event data can be very bursty, with large numbers of events arriving quickly (the queue builds up) and then there are quieter periods (the processor can catch up (hopefully))
2. The processor does catch up, from time to time.
3. There have been performance issues in the processing and, if the queue gets too large, a separate process purges the queue and generates events to rebuild the fact tables.
4. I don't have control over the structure of the log table, or the architecture of the processing system. Any changes to that are out of scope.
5. The processing of the events isn't the primary purpose of the external system. It's a add on to provide data to other parts of the business.

Comment: You need to post your index(es) definition. A single index won't necessarily be useful for this. But indexes should be the correct way to go, 140,000 rows isn't enough to cause any issues.

Comment: You'd also benefit from inspecting the execution plan as it often tells you where the issue lies.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and desired results? I'm having a hard time understanding if you want an even distribution of rows and average over intervals or just want to divide the results you get by the number of rows it returns. This will make a big difference to the average depending on the skew of activity (if everything happens in one hour, for example, the average for the day will be much smaller in the former case and much higher in the latter).

Comment: Why is Generated nullable? That seems like a flaw even if a null value is not possible given your usage. _The date and time the status was set_ You mean StateId which is an int? _average queue length for a day_ No you are not. Your query selects everything based on StateId.

Comment: @SMor I've updated the question to clarify a few things. The table structure is what it is, I can't control it, unfortunately. Yes I meant StateId. I've expanded the query to show how I'm doing the aggregates. The CTE gets the time the event is on the queue and the size of the queue at that point. The aggregate is trivial, but I should have included it for context. The CTE is the performance bottleneck.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've updated my question, I hope it clarifies things a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** this isn't the final answer as I am getting some minor value differences, but it's a couple of orders of magnitude faster. I'll try and refine it a bit more, but I wanted to get this out as a starting point.

I approached it in a different way and used Common Table Expressions (CTE)

1. Count events added (grouping by `Generated`) or removed (grouping by `Modified`).
2. Joining those together (`FULL OUTER JOIN` on the dates) gave me a list of times when the queue length changed, and by how much.
3. I found [this explanation on how to calculate a rolling sum](https://codingsight.com/calculating-running-total-with-over-clause-and-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server/) to give the length of the queue at points in time where it changed. (I didn't know that was possible prior to reading the link)
4. I then aggregated that based on the date.
5. I calculated aggregates of the event duration the original `EventLog` based on the date.
6. Finally I joined both aggregates on the dates

The final query is:

```
DECLARE @ActiveState INT = 0;
WITH 
    Added AS (
        SELECT Id, Generated AS Stamp, 1 AS Delta
            FROM EventLog 
            WHERE StateId != @ActiveState
    ),
    Removed AS (
        SELECT Id, Modified AS Stamp, -1 AS Delta
            FROM EventLog 
            WHERE StateId != @ActiveState),
    LengthChange AS (
        SELECT * FROM Added
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM Removed),
    RollingQueueLength AS (
        SELECT 
            Id, 
            Delta, 
            SUM(Delta) OVER(ORDER BY Stamp, Id) - Delta AS QueueLength -- don't include this row in total
            FROM LengthChange
    ),
    EventDuration AS (
        SELECT 
            Id,
            Generated, 
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, Generated, Modified)/60.0 TimeMinutes
            FROM EventLog 
            WHERE StateId != @ActiveState
    ),
    EventPerformance AS (
        SELECT
            EventDuration.Id,
            CAST(Generated AS DATE) GeneratedDate,
            TimeMinutes,
            QueueLength
            FROM EventDuration
                INNER JOIN RollingQueueLength
                    ON EventDuration.Id = RollingQueueLength.Id AND Delta = 1
    )
SELECT 
    GeneratedDate
    , AVG(TimeMinutes) AvgTime
    , AVG(QueueLength) AvgLength
    , COUNT(*) Count
FROM EventPerformance
GROUP BY GeneratedDate 
ORDER BY GeneratedDate DESC
```

The problem with the original query was that it was ***O(N<sup>2</sup>)*** and over 175k rows it just took a long time.